# How to humanize child input in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, humanize

```
@trainer = Trainer.new(trainer_params)
@trainer.name = @trainer.name.humanize
@trainer.surname = @trainer.surname.humanize
```

This bit works fine, but I would also like to apply the same thing to `Sportist` which `belongs_to :trainer` and

```
@trainer.sportists.name = @trainer.sportists.name.humanize
```

doesn't work, so how would I go about doing it? Note that this is a `nested form`.

Comment: `@trainer.sportists` is a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@trainer.sportists` is a collection (an `has_many` relation ?), try this:

```
@trainer.sportists.each { |sportist| sportist.name = sportist.name.humanize }
```